# Iterating through multiple lists in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory of lists. The lists contain file names:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

I need to process all of these lists, one list at a time, and wait between each list. I was attempting a nested for loop (i.e., for each list in MasterList or each list in DIR) but have been unable to find the proper syntax for such a venture.

Is a nested for loop the proper method? If so, could someone illustrate the proper structure? If that's not the correct approach, pointers welcome!

**ANSWERED**

Figured it out :-)

For those who need the syntax:

```
@echo off

FOR /f "tokens=*"  %%A IN (masterlist.txt) DO FOR /f "tokens=*" %%B IN (%%A) DO ECHO %%B
```

Just change "ECHO %%B" to the commands you want to apply.

Comment: Why not put your answer in an*Answer* and then accept that answer and thus closing off the question. Otherwise it remains as an open unanswered question.....